# Distance between edges

Tags: python, opencv, distance

I want to get the distance (drawn in red) out of this picture. So it is just a straight line from the outer detected edges. I am new to the whole images processing thing in openCV and I could not find a right solution online, so this is why I ask here. I hope somebody can help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to find all red pixels with coordinates, then subtract first and last one, rest is simple.

Comment: Is the red line really part of the image, or have you drawn it on to show what you mean but it won't normally be there? If you did just add it for explanation, please provide a second image without it for people to test with. Thank you.

Comment: Yes the red line is just to symbolize what the question is about. Ok yes i will provide that.

Comment: The second image is the original source, where I want to determine the width of the weld bead. And after some pre-processing steps I got the other picture, where the red line should show what distance I want to measure.

Comment: Now I see 2 different sized images with apparently unrelated content?

Comment: ok yes, I posted now the image without the red line. But this was just to show were the source was for the image. But nevertheless, my problem is, that I would like to know the distance between the outer edges, which should be symbolized with the red line in the first image.

Comment: If your image is representative, the obvious solution is to find the left-most white pixel and the right-most white pixel. Is that a good solution?

Comment: Yes that would be a possible solution, but how does the code look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do what I suggested in the comments. First sum down the columns, to get an image the same width as your original, but with just one row. Then look for the first and last column that don't sum to zero, i.e. the first and last column that are not completely black. I trimmed your image - please don't post screen shots else algorithms will find the window frames!

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image as greyscale
im = cv2.imread('weld.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Sum down the columns
columnTotals = np.sum(im, axis=0)

# Now look for non-zero (non-black) entries
nz = np.nonzero(columnTotals)

# Now get left and right edges of white parts of image
left, right = nz[0][0], nz[0][-1]              # (53,271)
```

Here is a visual representation of what the code is doing when summing down the columns:

[image]

`columnTotals` looks like this:

```
array([    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,   510,
       18870, 19890, 19890, 20400, 19890, 19890, 19125,  3060,  6120,
        6630,  6375,  6630,  6375,  6120,  5610,  5100,  5100,  5355,
        5355,  7140,  7395,  7650,  7395,  7395,  7905,  7650,  4335,
        4335,  4590,  5610,  6375,  6120,  6885,  6630,  6120,  5610,
        6375,  5865,  6120,  5100,  5100,  5355,  5865,  5865,  6120,
        5865,  5355,  5100,  5355,  5100,  4845,  4590,  4590,  4590,
        4590,  4590,  4590,  4590,  4845,  5355,  5865,  5865,  6375,
        5610,  5100,  5100,  4590,  4335,  3570,  3060,  2805,  2805,
        2550,  2295,  2805,  3570,  3570,  4080,  4080,  4335,  3825,
        3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,
        3825,  3825,  3825,  3825,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,
        3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,
        3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3315,  3315,  3315,
        3315,  3570,  3315,  3315,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,
        3570,  3570,  3570,  3570,  3825,  3570,  3570,  3315,  2805,
        2805,  2805,  2805,  2805,  3060,  3060,  3060,  3060,  3060,
        3060,  3060,  3060,  2805,  2805,  2295,  2295,  2550,  2805,
        2805,  3060,  3060,  3060,  2805,  2805,  2295,  1785,  1785,
        1785,  1785,  1785,  2040,  2040,  2295,  2550,  2295,  2295,
        2040,  2040,  1785,  1785,  1785,  2040,  1785,  2040,  1785,
        1785,  2295,  2295,  2295,  2295,  2040,  1785,  1785,  1785,
        1785,  1785,  1785,  2295,  3060,  3570,  4335,  4335,  4590,
        4845,  5100,  5355,  3570,  3570,  3060,  3060,  2040,  1785,
        2040,  2040,  2295,  3315, 11220, 11730, 11730, 11475, 10965,
        9945,  8670,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0], dtype=uint64)
```

`nz` looks like this:

```
(array([ 53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,
         66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,
         79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,
         92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104,
        105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117,
        118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130,
        131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143,
        144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156,
        157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169,
        170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182,
        183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195,
        196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208,
        209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221,
        222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234,
        235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247,
        248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260,
        261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271]),)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This works fine for my problem. So the distance that you get would be then 271-53 = 218. So the distance would be 218 pixel right?